# FileMaker Pro 10 - How to have cursor be in first field on new record?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, filemaker

When I start a new record in FileMaker is there a way for the cursor to automatically be in the first field so I can just start typing?  And to specify which field that should be?

**Background:**

I'm trying to set up a FileMaker layout for use with a barcode scanner.  So someone can scan in one record (there are two fields on the layout).  After scanning it should go to a new record and place the cursor in the scan field so it's ready to scan again.

I put a trigger on the scan field to run a script to create a new record after hitting the enter key in the one field.  After the new record statement I put a "go to field" statement but it doesn't seem to do anything.  It always goes to the other field instead of the scan field.

**Updates**

I just tried using a "set selection" statement in the script instead of "go to field" (I also tried using both one after the other).  Neither of those seemed to work.

I tried changing the tab order but it still goes to the other field instead of the scan field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a workaround.

I have just one field on the scan layout.  After a user scans, a script fires which changes the layout to one which shows all the information about the scanned record that was just entered.  It pauses for 1 second and then goes back to the scan layout for the next scan.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior when you create a new record is to go to the first field in the tab order, so this should work without you having to do anything.

The fact that it's not sounds to me like there might be a script trigger, either at the layout or field level, that's interfering with this or exiting the record. Try turning on the script debugger, create a new record, and see if a script runs.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out I had a second field.  Once I removed that it does work correctly.  But I want that second field to show information about the scan.  Whenever I add the second field in, the cursor seems to start in that field.

Comment: As Jesse said, the cursor goes to the first field *in tab order*. Try to edit the tab order (Layout mode, Layout menu, Set Tab Order).

Comment: @Mikhail, I tried that it didn't help.  It's very strange.  So clicking new record will set it in the first field in the tab order.  However running my script with only one statement (to create a new record) goes to the other field.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set your scanner to submit pre and post data keystrokes. We routinely use this to invoke a filemaker script pre-scan to "go to field", enter the data, then post-scan to "perform a find"

Answer (score 0):

I eventually devised a decent workaround with a second trigger script which seems to have no disadvantages.

However the tabs are set, I have found that an OnObjectExit trigger or an OnObjectSave trigger set up on the scan field will perform a script to process the scanned data, but the the step to return the cursor to the scan field will NOT work, probably because that field is still active in some way.

Rather than banging my head against I brick wall, I decided to set up an OnObjectExit trigger on the field to which the cursor is always deflected. This fires off a script to clear the scan field and then return the cursor to the scan field, ready for the next scan. This way, the cursor DOES arrive back where I want it.

Perhaps rather inelegant, but it works fine!

Comment: "*I have found that an OnObjectExit trigger or an OnObjectSave trigger set up on the scan field will perform a script to process the scanned data, but the the step to return the cursor to the scan field will NOT work, probably because that field is still active in some way.*" No, that's **not** a correct assessment of what happens. In fact, the script step **does** work. However, unless you exit the script with a false result, the triggering event will be executed immediately **after** the script.

Comment: ... So if you exit the scan field by tabbing to another field, the exit is put on hold, your script is executed, including the Go to Field step (which does nothing, since you still are in that field) - and only then the tab executes and you end up in the other field. -- The correct solution here is to exit the triggered script with a false result, thus cancelling the triggering event (and the lesson is understand the problem before devising a solution).